# Многопоточный запуск браузера

Tags: python, selenium, threading

В коде json файл в котором логин, пароль и id. При запуске двух потоков каждый поток дважды берет один и тот же id

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import json
import os
import sys
import threading


'''Json в котором собраны login, password, id аккаунтов'''
working_dir = os.path.sep.join(sys.argv[0].split(os.path.sep)[:-1])

with open(os.path.join(working_dir, "accounts.json"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    accounts = data["accounts"]


'''Функция которая открывает браузер и авторизует аккаунты'''
def auth_user():
    for account in accounts:
        print(account)
        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            s = Service("/Users/valiev/code/python/vkbot_playlist/chromedriver/chromedriver")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=auth_user, args=())
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

Как сделать чтоб первый поток брал первый элемент а второй поток следующий и так далее. При данном коде в консоль выводиться следующие:

```
{'id': '1'}
{'id': '1'}
{'id': '2'}
{'id': '2'}
{'id': '3'}
{'id': '3'}
{'id': '4'}
{'id': '4'}
{'id': '5'}
{'id': '5'}
{'id': '6'}
{'id': '6'}
{'id': '7'}
{'id': '7'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передать в функцию номер потока и один будет бежать по четным, а другой по нечетным элементам списка `accounts`:

```
def auth_user(t):
    for k in range(0 + t, len(accounts) + t, 2):
        if k >= len(accounts): # проверяем к , чтоб не вылететь за пределы списка.
            continue
        account = accounts[k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=auth_user, args=(i,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

В принципе, можно увеличить количество потоков, заменив 2 на 3,4, ... .

Comment: Помогло, только как остановить цикл когда дойдет до последнего элемента, а то щас цикл бесконечный

Comment: Цикл должен завершиться, когда закончатся элементы в списке.

Comment: Не завершается, идет по новой. Все нашел ошибку. Большое спасибо

Comment: в принципе рабочее решение, но выглядит как-то костыльно, предлагаю добавить просто новое поле - isUsed: false, и менять его на true, при взятии из объекта